# Contextual type 'AnyObject' cannot be used with dictionary literal - data structure not consistent

Tags: json, swift, dictionary

I'm trying to setup a simple dictionary in swift:

```
var dict = [
  "_id": "123",
  "profile": [
    "name": "me",
    "username": nil,
  ]
] as [String : Any]
```

However that fails with `Contextual type 'AnyObject' cannot be used with dictionary literal`. Following [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38065833/2054629), I've tried replacing `[String : Any]` by `[String : [String : Any]]`, but that logically fails because the first value is of type `String` and not `[String : Any]`.

I'd just want to have something that holds any kind of data I can represent as a json, and I'm fine with having to guard-cast things when trying to access them later on.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Swift is a strictly typed language, so the the problem is that when you add `nil` to dictionary, it won't be able to know what type its *values* going to be so it'll complain saying the type is ambiguous.

You can specify the type of keys and values of the dictionary by doing the following:

```
let profile: [String: AnyObject?] = ["name": "me", "username": nil]    
let dict = ["_id": "123", "profile": profile] as [String : Any]
```

Alternatively, you can use [`init(dictionaryLiteral:)`](https://developer.apple.com/library/tvos/documentation/Swift/Reference/Swift_Dictionary_Structure/index.html#//apple_ref/swift/structctr/Dictionary/s:FVs10DictionarycFt17dictionaryLiteralGSaTxq____GS_xq__) constructor to create the dictionary:

```
let dict = [
  "_id": "123",
  "profile": Dictionary<String, AnyObject?>(dictionaryLiteral: ("name", "me"), ("username", nil))
] as [String : Any]
```

Comment: I see. Still it's weird that things get messy like that. Anyway if I follow your answer, I then gets `JSONSerialization.isValidJSONObject(dict)` to be `false`. Any idea of what's going on? Json has no issue of anything close to strictly typed so I'd except that to be just fine.

Comment: @Guig that is a different issue which has nothing to do with the problem you had above. could you please ask that as a separate question on SO?

Comment: Sure thing. Here it is: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39221541/swift-dictionary-with-nil-value-to-json

Comment: I think the problem is not Guig is trying to add nil into dictionary but it is the new Swift compiler doesn't allow the usage of literal dictionary for `AnyObject`

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, splitting things up works as well:

```
let insideDict = [
    "name": "me",
    "username": nil,
  ]

var dict = [String : Any]()
dict["_id"] = "123"
dict["profile"] = insideDict
```