# Swift - dictionary with nil value to JSON

Tags: json, swift, dictionary, casting

I've a dictionary with optional values:

```
let user = [
  "name": "gui",
  "username": nil,
] as [String: Any?]
```

that I simply want to cast to a json that should be `{"name": "gui", username: null}`

However, `JSONSerialization.isValidJSONObject(user)` returns `false`, and `try JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: user)` fails..

How should I handle that?

Comment: if there is no user  name then put empty string as username instead of nil

Comment: JSSONSerialization cannot handle optionals. You have to use `NSNull()`, which is mapped to `null` in the JSON data.

Comment: @Shan I disagree, there's quite a difference between null and "", or between null and 0

Comment: @MartinR that seems to work but it's very annoying because an optional `MyClass?` cannot be set to `NSNull()` Is there no better option? What the duplicated question I could not found?

Comment: JSONSerialization handles only a limited set of types: dictionaries, arrays, strings, dates, numbers, nulls, but not custom classes. – The duplicate appears now at the top of your question.